# Can't Find State roaming in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trialing Azure AD (premium) . I can't find enterprise state roaming anywhere.  This page ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-windows-enterprise-state-roaming-enable )  is nothing like what the portal is, and I can't switch back to the classic portal ( I assume that is where I would have done it before ) .

So the specific question is:  How do I get roaming profiles operating in the Azure portal ( given that the docs above don't describe it )

Surely Microsoft wouldn't upgrade things, leave the documentation out of date and/ or leave this feature out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the new portal you can find it in users and groups / device settings

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I guess it would be great if they updated the docs!